# JavaFX ImagePane resize Bad Quality

Tags: java, css, image-processing, javafx

How do I render the image with a better quality?

The node is a Pane with the css:

```
.imagePane {
    -fx-background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -fx-background-image: url('../../img/logo/icon_white.png');
    -fx-background-size: cover; 
}
```

Image inside the application:

[image: Image inside the application]

Default Image:
[image: Default Image]

Link to PSD:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YK52wzjJg3c2NFc0NSTDNKWGM/view?usp=sharing

I tried to put the best image quality but it still cause pixelation

Comment: Is the ratio the same from the original? That may cause some pixelation.

Comment: @HypnicJerk, Yes, it is the same.

Comment: Try to use source image in higher resolution

Comment: @RawnaldGregoryErickson, I doubled the resolution and still caus pixelation

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try to initialize a Background in the Java code.
You can set the background into a pane.

```
Pane#setBackground(background);
```

if you initialize a Background you would first initialize a BackgroundImage and a BackgroundImage needs an Image. In the constructor of the image you can define the requestedWith and requestedHeight. These are the properties in which resolution the files should be loaded.
The final code could look like this.

```
pane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundImage(new Image(inputStream, 500, 500, true, true), BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.CENTER, new BackgroundSize(pane.getWidth(), pane.getHeight(), false, false, false, true))));
```

In this case the image would be loaded with a resolution of 500 x 500 and resized into pane.getHeight and pane.getWith.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried this but still get pixelation. Any changes...

Answer (score 0):

The original image is `307 X 594`. You cannot expect that it would smoothly be resized down. It would be better to use something more scalable.

However it tried to load it from a java code saving ratio and with smooth scaling, it seems to crate bearable results. I do not see a way how to do it in css. So, i suggest you do rescaling programmatically.

I have a simple program here which you can use for experimenting.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundImage;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundPosition;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundRepeat;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundSize;
import javafx.stage.Stage;;

public class MyImage extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();

    Image img = new Image("file:/image.png", 55, 0, true, true);
    System.out.println("Image: " + img.getHeight() + " X " + img.getWidth());
    BackgroundImage bgImage = new BackgroundImage(img, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
        BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);

    Background bg = new Background(bgImage);
    root.setBackground(bg);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried your code but still not good, I just attached the PSD version of the image

Comment: I wonder if the issue is with your device screen resolution and/or color resolution. can you reproduce it on a different screen?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nothing to do with CSS or Java code, It's an image processing issue that when you reduce the size of an image, the quality and sharpness of edge will be distorted.
As @serge mentioned, your image dimensions are 307 in height and 594 in width, so you should find the exact reduced `width` and `height` correspondent to your `aspect ratio`, you can use tools like [Image aspect ratio and resizing calculator](http://red-route.org/code/image-resizing-calculator) to find the best numbers for your purpose. I used your image on `93 X 180` pane, and the result was like this:
[image: JavafX simple test]

As you see on my `Hello World!` sample, the left image quality is not good enough, especially in edges and borders.

> ### Solutions:
>
> 1. Resize the image in your desired
>      dimensions using tools like **Photoshop**. you can get more
>      information in
>      [How To
>      Resize An Image on Photoshop And Keep It Sharp](https://www.sitepoint.com/resize-an-image-in-photoshop/)
>
>    Convert your
>      original **PNG** images to a vector format like **SVG**.You can use
>      some online tools like [ONLINE PNG TO SVG
>      CONVERTER](http://pngtosvg.com)

Comment: No, it doesnt make any changes. Here is a link to a better quality image https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0YK52wzjJg3cU8weGFiYnJiQlU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I agree on this. But there is another problem: If you have your image at the "correct" resolution for a 100% screen (by creating a bitmap image out of photoshop or with a SVG image) you will have problems at a 125% screen scale factor.
The very best (IMHO) would be to draw the shapes directly in a Canvas, or draw it via javafx.scene.shape.SVGPath